# How to disable orientation Landscape in app and our website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

i want to disable orientation:Landscape in our app and website using jquery.
so please help me for disable in app and website.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: i do not know any code for disable so i have no code so please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure it will work, but Try this

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#landscape{
         position: absolute;
         top: 0px;
         left: 0px;
         background: #000000;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         display: none; 
         z-index: 20000;
         opacity: 0.9;
         margin:0 auto;
}
#landscape div{

        color: #FFFFFF;                                  
        opacity: 1;
        top: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
}
</style>
<script>          
      function doOnOrientationChange()
      {
        switch(window.orientation) 
        {  
          case -90:                 
                 document.getElementById("landscape").style.display="block";
                 break;
          case 90:              
                document.getElementById("landscape").style.display="block";                 
                break;
         default:                   
                document.getElementById("landscape").style.display="none";
                break;                            
        }
      }

      //Listen to orientation change
      window.addEventListener('orientationchange', doOnOrientationChange);  

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="doOnOrientationChange();">
<div id="landscape"><div>"Rotate Device to Portrait"</div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you this code are working.

Comment: you welcome....

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, **You can not force orientation on a web page**, but you can show some information in content when user is in landscape mode.

To do that **take help of media queries and check the orientation**, in the landscape stylesheet(style_landscape.css) hide everything and show a message that your app can't be opened on landscape and the user must revert to portrait mode to continue.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_landscape.css" media="screen and (orientation: landscape)">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_portrait.css" media="screen and (orientation: portrait)">
```